# How can I fetch rows upto some condition for multiple group of ids

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jpql

How can I fetch rows up-to some condition for multiple groups

Please refer below my_table currently applied order by 
(1) fk_user_id in ascending (2) created_date in descending

I am using postgresql and spring boot jpa, jpql.

1)  Please find query to create table and insert data as below

Create and insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
  id bigint,
  condition boolean,
  fk_user_id bigint,
  created_date date
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.my_table
  OWNER TO postgres;

INSERT INTO public.my_table(
            id, condition, fk_user_id, created_date)
    VALUES 
    (137, FALSE, 23, '2019-08-28'),
    (107, FALSE, 23, '2019-05-13'),
    (83, TRUE, 23, '2019-04-28'),
    (78, FALSE, 23, '2019-04-07'),
    (67, TRUE, 23, '2019-03-18'),
    (32, FALSE, 23, '2019-01-19'),
    (181, FALSE, 57, '2019-11-04'),
    (158, TRUE, 57, '2019-09-27'),
    (146, FALSE, 57, '2019-09-16'),
    (125, FALSE, 57, '2019-07-24'),
    (378, TRUE, 71, '2020-02-16'),
    (228, TRUE, 71, '2019-12-13'),
    (179, FALSE, 71, '2019-10-06'),
    (130, FALSE, 71, '2019-08-19'),
    (114, TRUE, 71, '2019-06-29'),
    (593, FALSE, 92, '2020-03-02'),
    (320, FALSE, 92, '2020-01-30'),
    (187, FALSE, 92, '2019-11-23'),
    (180, TRUE, 92, '2019-10-17'),
    (124, FALSE, 92, '2019-08-05');
```

[image: my_table]

I would like to fetch all the rows which have **ALL latest FALSE condition upto last TRUE found** and then skip other rows for that user.

For ex.,

1) User id = 23 -- First 2 rows with id (137, 107) will fetch as on 2019-04-28, it has TRUE condition and so, will skip other rows

2) User id = 57 -- Only 1 row with id (181)

3) User id = 71 -- No rows will be fetch as it has latest TRUE condition

likewise, my result rows should be like as below.

[image]

I can find rows for only 1 user with below query

```
select * from user_condition where 
fk_user_id = 23 and created_date > (select max(created_date) from user_condition where fk_user_id = 23 and condition like 'TRUE' group by fk_user_id);
```

**But, I want rows for all fk_user_id**

Comment: Please post data as text, not images. It makes it much easier to build an answer if there is data that can be worked with.

Comment: Yep. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Nick : As you said, I have describe queries to create and insert data. As I can not paste table here and data as text was not looks proper

Comment: @Strawberry : As I go through your link, I followed the same here and posted Create and Insert queries now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM sourcetable t1
WHERE t1.condition = 'FALSE'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM sourcetable t2
                   WHERE t1.fk_user_id = t2.fk_user_id 
                     AND t1.created_date < t2.created_date /* or <= */
                     AND t2.condition = 'TRUE' )
```